# LinkedIn REST Profile API only returning lite_profile response

Tags: ios, swift, scope, response, linkedin-api

I have an old iOS application which has the **LinkedIn** APIs integrated. Now, I want to migrate to v2 since LinkedIn started deprecating v1. So, I changed the login flow to `OAuth2`, obtained an `access_token` and included in the header for the Profile API.

```
["Authorization": "Bearer " + access_token]
```

For the api : `https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me`, the response was similar to that of r_liteprofile response, but for other apis like `https://api.linkedin.com/v2/people/(id:{profile ID})?projection=(id,firstName,lastName,industryId~)`, the response was

> **403: Not enough permissions to access**

Since my application already has the `r_fullprofile` permission(as we can see from the developer console), I have added the same in the authorization endpoint. I want to get all the details from the `r_basicprofile` and `r_fullprofile` like educations, industry etc. Someone please help!

Comment: can you try to follow all step from here : https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/oauth2

Comment: @Miteshjadav i have already followed the same..